# Why is there a vertical gap between these divs?

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, margin

For some reason on Chrome I have a "lime" colored `1px` line between the "top" and the "bod".  When I remove the `overflow` css directive the line goes away.

I can only see the "lime" line in Chrome and not in Firefox.

[image]

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/m36yk1o9/5/

```css
#chatApplicationClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lime;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

#chatHeaderClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-top: 0px solid red;
  border-left: 0px solid red;
  border-right: 0px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chatHeaderTextClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffff33;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#chatHeaderArrowClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #9900ff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#chatBodyClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 5px solid pink;
  border-right: 5px solid pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.chatAgentBubbleClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #664eff;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chatVisitorBubbleClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #6600ff;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chatAgentBubbleTextClassic {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: lightblue;
}

.chatVisitorBubbleTextClassic {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatApplicationClassic">
  <div id="chatHeaderClassic">
    <div id="chatHeaderArrowClassic">
      Arr
    </div>
    <div id="chatHeaderTextClassic">
      Top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chatBodyClassic">
    bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br />
  </div>
  <!--
 <div id="chatFooterClassic">
  <div id="chatInputContainerClassic">
   <input placeholder="type here..." id="chatInputClassic" type="text" /> 
  </div>
  <div id="chatSendButton">
   <div id="chatSendButtonText">Send</div>
  </div>
 </div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Viewing on chrome, can't see the issue in the fiddle.

Comment: I added a picture.  I am using Chrome 48 on a macbook air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably from the two child elements in the header. The `padding` makes one of the box taller than the container, with `float` set there it causes overflow, as you didn't set any clearfix there.

But since you have `float:right` set on "Top", just set `float:left` on "Arr", and clear the floats by adding `overflow:hidden` on the container. That thin lime line will be removed.

**[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m36yk1o9/7/)**

```css
#chatApplicationClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lime;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

#chatHeaderClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-top: 0px solid red;
  border-left: 0px solid red;
  border-right: 0px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden; /*added*/
}

#chatHeaderTextClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffff33;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  float: left; /*added*/
}

#chatHeaderArrowClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #9900ff;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#chatBodyClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 5px solid pink;
  border-right: 5px solid pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.chatAgentBubbleClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #664eff;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chatVisitorBubbleClassic {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #6600ff;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chatAgentBubbleTextClassic {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: lightblue;
}

.chatVisitorBubbleTextClassic {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatApplicationClassic">
  <div id="chatHeaderClassic">
    <div id="chatHeaderArrowClassic">
      Arr
    </div>
    <div id="chatHeaderTextClassic">
      Top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chatBodyClassic">
    bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br /> bod
    <br />
  </div>
  <!--
 <div id="chatFooterClassic">
  <div id="chatInputContainerClassic">
   <input placeholder="type here..." id="chatInputClassic" type="text" /> 
  </div>
  <div id="chatSendButton">
   <div id="chatSendButtonText">Send</div>
  </div>
 </div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your padding from 6px to 5px:

```
#chatHeaderArrowClassic {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                border:0;
                color:#9900ff;
                display:inline-block;
                float:right;
                padding:5px;
                font-size:18px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi,

It looks like the parent element has a background color of lime and if you hide the #chatHeaderClassic background-color it shows through.Proof:

```
#chatApplicationClassic {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 30px;
width: 300px;
background-color: lime;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
```

}

So just change that above code to:

```
#chatApplicationClassic {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 30px;
width: 300px;
background-color: pink;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
```

}

Hope this helps.
Regards

Comment: Hi Jannik, thanks for the comment, but I set the colors that way just to illustrate the gap